# React Router V6 full stop making URL invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using `useRoutes` and `Outlet`. I have the following route example:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard/>,
    children: [
      { path: "/*", element: <Profile /> },
      { path: "/*/example", element: <Example/> },
    ],
  }
]

const App= () => {
  const route = useRoutes(routes)
  return <div>{route}</div>
}
```

I want to push user_id to the url so for example `/user1` this loads the  component as expected however when I type something like `/firstname.surname` I get the follow error `Cannot GET /firstname.surname` however `/firstname.surname/example` does load the component

This is due to the full stop in the Id. How can I resolve this and accept it as a valid URL?

When I update path for dashboard to `""` it seems to work however when I do something like `/foo.bar/test` it loads profile component how do I restrict this as this path does not exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard/>,
    children: [
      { path: "/:id", element: <Profile /> },
      { path: "/:id/example", element: <Example/> },
    ],
  }
]

const App= () => {
  const route = useRoutes(routes)
  return <div>{route}</div>
}
```

"*" is a generic wildcard need to pass id like above

Answer (score 1):

I think the wildcard in `{ path: "/*/example", element: <Example/> }` doesn't work well with other routes also specifying the wildcard. It's my understanding that the `"/*"` is valid only at the end of the path to indicate matching more deeply nested routes.

The following config seems to work though, using a named path param.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard />,
    children: [
      { path: "/*", element: <Profile /> },
      { path: "/:path/example", element: <Example /> }
    ]
  }
];
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-full-stop-making-url-invalid]

Comment: You were right drew, I had to replace wildcard * to :id. I thought in V6 * was equal to :id according to the docs...